# Why can't we get the text of title tag without getTitle() method

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am curious about tags inside head section especially title tag. Why can't we get text inside that tag like other tags used inside body section? As example:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getText();
```

I think, it's a meta tag & there will be only one of it(If I am wrong, correct me). So, selenium provides special method like getTitle()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selenium method `getText()` returns the displayed text. So calling `getText()` on the title tag will return an empty string since it is not rendered in the page.

To get the textual content, read the 'textContent' attribute/property :

```
element.getAttribute("textContent")
```

Spec and default implementation: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-text
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L944